# Stateless react functions shows invalid proptype even though it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-proptypes

I have a stateless react component that looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Goal from './Goal'
import {List} from 'material-ui/List';
import {PropTypes as MobxPropTypes} from 'mobx-react';

const propTypes = {
    goals: MobxPropTypes.ObservableArray,
    onClick: PropTypes.function
};

const GoalsList = ({goals, onClick}) =>(
        <List>
            {goals.map((goal) => (
                <Goal
                    key={goal.name}
                    name={goal.name}
                    onClick={() => {
                        onClick(goal)
                    }}
                />
            ))}
        </List>);


GoalsList.propTypes = propTypes;
export default GoalsList;
```

I use this component as follows:

```
<GoalList goals={this.props.store.goals}
          onClick={this.props.store.selectGoal}/>
```

And that's how `goals` and `selectGoal` are defined in the store:

**selectGoal**:

```
@action selectGoal = (goal) => {
    this.selectedGoal = goal;
}
```

**goals**:

```
@observable goals = [];
```

Still I'm getting the following warnings in the console:

> Failed prop type: GoalList: prop type `goals` is invalid; it
>   must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but
>   received `undefined`.

And:

> Failed prop type: GoalList: prop type `onClick` is invalid; it must
>   be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received
>   `undefined`

When I debug the render function that renders `GoalList` I see that `goals` is `ObservableArray` and `onClick` is a function. I can't figure out why I keep getting these warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is how you're defining your prop types. Your code itself is fine and I'm guessing everything works as expected.

The prop type for a function is `PropTypes.func`, not `PropTypes.function`, so that should fix the warning you see about `onClick`.

The mobx prop type for an observable array is `observableArray` (lowercase o).

So, at the end your `propTypes` should look like this:

```
const propTypes = {
    goals: MobxPropTypes.observableArray,
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
};
```

The warning message is kind of confusing, but it makes sense once you know what is going on:

> prop type onClick is invalid; it must be a function

React PropTypes are supposed to be functions that return true if the provided type matches the desired type.

> but received undefined

But, because you had `function` instead of `func`, the PropTypes ended up being `undefined` instead of a function and so the prop types verifier couldn't work properly.

Comment: My most embarrassing question in SO so far :)
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: To be fair, the error message could definitely be a lot clearer about the cause of the problem and how to fix it. Glad I could help and happy coding!